# Binding a List<List<object> to DataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have a object with the following format

```cs
public class SomeObject {
    public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<List<object>> Rows { get; set; } = new List<List<object>>();
}
```

The `ColumnNames` and `Rows` property will have identical slots.
Eg. if there are 5 column names there will be 5 slots in the `Rows` collection.

I want to bind the `Rows` property to the `DataGridView`.
Also I want to  display `ColumnNames` as headers in the `DataGridView`.

My current code is

```cs
var dgv = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = instance of SomeObject ;
bs.DataMember = "Rows";
dgv.DataSource = bs;
```

From this I get an output like this

[image: DataGridView]

What is the correct way to Bind `List<List<object>>` to the `DataGridView` also how do you set the columns from another list after binding the grid.

I want the grid to autoupdate when the `Rows` collection changes.

Comment: If you were to bind to a `List<T>` such as `List<Animal>` you'd see that the columns automagically created were named after the **public  properties** of your `Animal` class.  However, `object` does t really have many useful properties.  Columns by the way are not just string names - they have a datatype as well which allows the DGV to be extremely powerful.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp yes I would have liked to use something like what you describe. However the same `SomeObject` can have different instances with different column names and different data types which I can't predict ahead of time as these are dynamically created.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `ObservableCollection<T>` class and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to achieve what you want.

Comment: @dropoutcoder I tried doing something like `BindingList<List<object>>`  for the `Rows` collection, but it didn't work as expected, I guess you do need Model classes  for Binding unless of course I'm missing something.